# Intuitive understanding of chi-squared variance

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, chi-squared-distribution

The chi-square distribution is a sampling distribution of normal variance.

A chi-square distribution with $m$ degrees of freedom can be expressed as sum of squares of $m$ i.i.d standard normal variables.

Its variance is $2m$ and expected value is $m$.

Now, if we plot the sum of $m$ standard normal variables, the variance is actually reduced by a factor of $m$ ($\sigma^2/m$).
But in the case of chi-square distribution as $m$ increases, the variance actually increases.
Why would squaring the variable increase the variance? Intuitively, as we sum the squares of more & more variables, the variance should decrease.

Comment: **Averages** do tend to have smaller variances than their components, but **sums** tend to have larger variances.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I now realize that. I was mistaking between sum of normal variables & their mean.